# Sql code to create the Mirror image of the string in Oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Team,

I need a sql query or function which will create the mirror image of string.

Thanks
Rajeev

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If "mirror" is reversed text use:

```
SELECT REVERSE('my_text') FROM dual;
```

## EDIT:

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f37cd/5/0)**

```
SELECT t
    ,REVERSE(t)  AS Mirror1
    ,TRANSLATE(t, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',N'ɐqɔpǝɟbɥıظʞןɯuodbɹsʇnʌʍxʎz') AS Mirror2
    ,TRANSLATE(REVERSE(t), 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',N'ɐqɔpǝɟbɥıظʞןɯuodbɹsʇnʌʍxʎz') AS Mirror3
FROM tab;
```

[image]

Comment: Mirror is not reversed text .

Comment: @raju: so...we're supposed to guess what you mean by "mirror"? That's why this question was closed - we don't understand what you mean, and you don't seem willing to explain it. If you'd like to get an answer to this question then go and EDIT YOUR QUESTION, add further explanation and perhaps an example of what you've tried thus far, and maybe it'll get re-opened and answered. Best of luck.